# redis.lrange is not a function running in node.js and redis

Tags: node.js, redis

I am working on the latest redis with node.js.

I have run the similar code as below which works out.

```
const client = redis.createClient();
await client.connect();
let lastMsg = await client.get("device:"+id);
await client.disconnect();
```

But running the code below troubles me

```
const redis = require("redis");
const id = 1;
const client = redis.createClient();
await client.connect();
let results = await client.lrange(`device:messages:${id}`, 0, -1);
await client.disconnect();
```

when running the code, it throws out an error saying "TypeError: client.lrange is not a function". I don't figure out what goes wrong .

Comment: `lRange`, not lrange by [example](https://github.com/redis/node-redis/blob/118dc111918fb0ae342bc25408d95209c4b20e53/packages/client/lib/commands/LRANGE.spec.ts#L16)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Node Redis implements all the Redis commands in camelCase and uppercase, but not lowercase. So, you need to do this:

```js
let results = await client.lRange(`device:messages:${id}`, 0, -1);
```

Or:

```js
let results = await client.LRANGE(`device:messages:${id}`, 0, -1);
```

I think the former looks more like JavaScript but you do you.